# op amp - current source - voltage output

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current-source, output

I have the electronic schematic bellow composed with two op amp and I want to determine the voltage output of the X2 op Amp.

[image]

I m a little bit confusing about the aim of using the zener diode D1 in such circuit. So could any one help me to understand how to determine the Voltage output Vout of the op amp X2 ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Excuse me, but the current through R1 is V1/R1 only if the bottom end of R1 is at GND and the inputs of opamp X1 were swapped. Please, check these and fix the question.

Comment: @user287001: Thanks for your reply. I have swapped the VIN+ and VIN-

Comment: But the current through R1 is not V1/R1, X1 sets the voltage between the emitter of Q1 and GND equal to V1.

Comment: @user287001: Thanks for your reply. I have removed the phrase saying that th current through R1 is equal to V1/R1

Comment: Where did you get this circuit? Doesn't the original source give you some idea of how the circuit is supposed to work?

Comment: Is there something wrong in my schematic ?